# Expected unqualified-id error?

Tags: objective-c

```
//GDataYouTubeMediaElements.m
- (void)setIsPrivate:(BOOL)flag 
 {
    if (flag) 
        {
          GDataYouTubePrivate *private = [GDataYouTubePrivate            implicitValue];
          [self setObject:private forExtensionClass:[GDataYouTubePrivate  class]];

        } 
      else 
        {
          [self setObject:nil forExtensionClass:[GDataYouTubePrivate class]];
        }

    }
}
```

In the above code before the private object, I'm getting this error:

> Expected unqualified-id

Comment: Just so you know your method should **NOT** be called `setIsPrivate:` is should be `setPrivate:` and then the getter would be called `isPrivate`. Try and stick to coding conventions it will make your life a lot easier down the line

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` after the `else {}` block. 
Correct version:

```
//GDataYouTubeMediaElements.m
- (void)setIsPrivate:(BOOL)flag 
 {
    if (flag) 
    {
        GDataYouTubePrivate *private = [GDataYouTubePrivate implicitValue];
        [self setObject:private forExtensionClass:[GDataYouTubePrivate class]];
    } 
    else 
    {
        [self setObject:nil forExtensionClass:[GDataYouTubePrivate class]];
    }
}
```